# Can't connect to SSH using PuTTY | Windows 10

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm on a Windows 10 machine and have installed PuTTY. I'm trying to connect, but I get this error after entering my Host IP and opening the session:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2020.12.30 17:23:14 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Event Log: Looking up host "192.168.1.121" for SSH connection
Event Log: Connecting to 192.168.1.121 port 22
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.74
Outgoing raw data at 2020-12-30 17:23:14
  00000000  53 53 48 2d 32 2e 30 2d 50 75 54 54 59 5f 52 65  SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Re
  00000010  6c 65 61 73 65 5f 30 2e 37 34 0d 0a              lease_0.74..
Event Log: Failed to connect to 192.168.1.121: Network error: Connection refused
Event Log: Network error: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you connect to this host from some other device? Is there a firewall in place?

Comment: Side note: are you aware that w10 ships with ssh command line, and thus makes putty less useful?

Comment: @SteveB I guess the graphical UI putty provides (e.g. session management) still has its advantages for people who like it. I personally have dumped putty several months ago after having lost patience with its own key format - I want my keys protected by the advanced key format (`-o` option, now standard) which putty couldn't handle for ages. I have read that it can in the meantime, but it's too late; I won't switch back. However, I wanted my SSH to be as close as possible to the original, so I use cygwin, not the native Windows SSH.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the solution is in the log you showed.

`Connection refused`, simply and not completely precise, means that your client can connect to the server, and that the server recognizes that your client wants to connect, but the **server** refuses the connection.

A server refusing a connection is different from network timeouts, wrong routes and similar problems. It means that the network in general works as expected, except the server itself.

In nearly all cases I saw refused connections were due to a firewall on the server or due to server software not running (on the expected port and interface).

In your case, you should investigate the **server** and make sure

- that the SSH server software is running at all
- that the SSH server software is using the port you expect (sometimes server admins move SSH to an unusual port, e.g. 2222 instead of 22, because they consider this a small piece of additional security)
- that the SSH server listens on the correct interface (provided the server has more than one)
- that the server does not prevent incoming SSH connections at all, e.g. via firewall rules

Please note that your problem could also be due to a firewall *between* your client and the server (i.e. not on the server itself) or a few other more exotic reasons, but none of them is as likely as one of the reasons outlined above.

Comment: +1 for detailing various common possibilities.  There are more, like the SSH server only listening on a certain interface.  But the information here is right, and the main, most common causes are listed.  Nicely done, Binarus.

Comment: @TOOGAM Thanks for the hint - I have added the server listening on the wrong interface to the possible reasons.